# python django soaplib response with classmodel issue

Tags: python, soap, xml-namespaces, tns, soaplib

I run a soap server in django.

Is it possible to create a soap method that returns a soaplib classmodel instance without <{method name}Response><{method name}Result> tags?

For example, here is a part of my soap server code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
from soaplib.core.service import rpc, DefinitionBase, soap
from soaplib.core.model.primitive import String, Integer, Boolean
from soaplib.core.model.clazz import Array, ClassModel 
from soaplib.core import Application
from soaplib.core.server.wsgi import Application as WSGIApplication
from soaplib.core.model.binary import Attachment    


class documentResponse(ClassModel):
    __namespace__ = ""
    msg = String
    hash = String


class MyService(DefinitionBase):
    __service_interface__ = "MyService"


    __port_types__ = ["MyServicePortType"]




    @soap(String, Attachment, String ,_returns=documentResponse,_faults=(MyServiceFaultMessage,)  , _port_type="MyServicePortType"  )
    def sendDocument(self, fileName, binaryData, hash ):

        binaryData.file_name = fileName
        binaryData.save_to_file()


        resp = documentResponse()
        resp.msg = "Saved"
        resp.hash = hash
        return resp
```

and it  responses like that:

```
 <senv:Body>
   <tns:sendDocumentResponse>
     <tns:sendDocumentResult>
      <hash>14a95636ddcf022fa2593c69af1a02f6</hash>
      <msg>Saved</msg>
    </tns:sendDocumentResult>
  </tns:sendDocumentResponse>
</senv:Body>
```

But i need a response like this:

```
<senv:Body>
   <ns3:documentResponse>
     <hash>A694EFB083E81568A66B96FC90EEBACE</hash>
     <msg>Saved</msg>
  </ns3:documentResponse>
</senv:Body>
```

What kind of configurations should i make in order to get that second response i mentioned above ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u.unver34 can you share what worked for you?

Comment: Sure, I used none of the methods above, I found a different way. I replaced that unwanted tags and all the response scheme tree  with the  tree form i needed at the return point of django soap server, according to some keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Python's SoapLib yet, but had the same problem while using .NET soap libs. Just for reference, in .NET this is done using the following decorator:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

I've looked in the soaplib source, but it seems it doesn't have a similar decorator. The closest thing I've found is the `_style` property. As seen from the code  https://github.com/soaplib/soaplib/blob/master/src/soaplib/core/service.py#L124 - when using

```
@soap(..., _style='document')
```

it doesn't append the `%sResult` tag, but I haven't tested this. Just try it and see if this works in the way you want it.

If it doesn't work, but you still want to get this kind of response, look at Spyne:

http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/decorator.html

It is a fork from soaplib(I think) and has the `_soap_body_style='bare'` decorator, which I believe is what you want.